# BMI Calculator returns 0 every time

Tags: java

So I am making a BMI calculator that gives the user an option between imperial and metric. However whenever the imperial bmi is calculated it is returned as 0. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the values not being saved.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMICalculator {

public static double lbWeight = 0;
public static double inchHeight = 0;
public static double kgWeight = 0;
public static double mHeight = 0;
public static double imperialBMI = 0;
public static double metricBMI = 0;
public static String userName;

public static void programIntroduction()
{
    System.out.print("Welcome to the BMI Calculator, please enter your name:");
    Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
    userName = scannerName.nextLine();
}

public static void getLBWeight()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter your weight from 22 to 660 LB:");
    Scanner scannerWeight = new Scanner(System.in);
    lbWeight = scannerWeight.nextDouble();

    for (;lbWeight<22;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerWeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        lbWeight = scannerWeight2.nextDouble();
    }

    for (;lbWeight>660;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerWeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        lbWeight = scannerWeight2.nextDouble();
    }
}

public static void getInchHeight()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter your height from 20 to 120 inches:");
    Scanner scannerHeight = new Scanner(System.in);
    inchHeight = scannerHeight.nextDouble();

    for (;inchHeight<20;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid height:");
        Scanner scannerHeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        inchHeight = scannerHeight2.nextDouble();
    }

    for (;inchHeight>120;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid height:");
        Scanner scannerHeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        inchHeight = scannerHeight2.nextDouble();
    }

}

public static void getKGWeight()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter your weight from 10 to 300 KG:");
    Scanner scannerWeightKG = new Scanner(System.in);
    kgWeight = scannerWeightKG.nextInt();

    for (;kgWeight<10;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerWeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        kgWeight = scannerWeight2.nextInt();
    }

    for (;kgWeight>300;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerWeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        kgWeight = scannerWeight2.nextInt();
    }
}

public static void getMHeight()
{
    System.out.print("Please enter your height from .5 to 3 M:");
    Scanner scannerHeightM = new Scanner(System.in);
    mHeight = scannerHeightM.nextInt();

    for (;mHeight<.5;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerHeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        mHeight = scannerHeight2.nextInt();
    }

    for (;mHeight>3;)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid weight:");
        Scanner scannerHeight2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        mHeight = scannerHeight2.nextInt();
    }
}

public static void ImperialBMI()
{
    imperialBMI = (lbWeight*703)/(inchHeight*inchHeight);   
}

public static void MetricBMI()
{
    metricBMI = (kgWeight)/(mHeight*mHeight);

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    programIntroduction();
    System.out.println("Please type 1 for imperial mode or 2 for metric mode:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    if (userInput == 1)
    {
        getLBWeight();
        getInchHeight();
        System.out.println(imperialBMI);
    }
    if (userInput == 2)
    {
        getKGWeight();
        getMHeight();
        System.out.println(metricBMI);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to create a new `Scanner` every time you read something. You can just create one scanner as a static variable and use that.

Answer (score 3):

You initialized `imperialBMI` and `metricBMI` to `0`, but you never call the methods that calculate their values.  Call `MetricBMI()` or `ImperialBMI()` before outputting the corresponding variable.